# Postgres SQL insert into boolean column true if exists in another table

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres 10.3

I have two tables:

```
table1 

pk  | term(varchar) | is_in_dictionary(bool)
--------------------------------------------
 1  | abcdef        |
 2  | coffee        |
 3  | fdjk          |
 4  | dog           |
```

table2 is a simple English dictionary

```
pk  | word (varchar) 
---------------------
1   | ad
2   | ads
3   | all
```

I want to insert TRUE in the empty column if term is found in table2 and FALSE if not found.

Please help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 SET is_in_dictionary = TRUE 
    WHERE term IN 
    (SELECT word FROM table2) ;
```

Try this. Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it! I spent way too much time trying to figure this out by googling... should've asked earlier. That syntax is actually much simpler than I expected :) Many thanks